# sending variables into external running windows application in C#

Tags: c#

I have a windows application, that expects 2 variables and than produce a result.
How can I launch that application through c# program without using the argv parameters, I need to send the variables during the application runtime.

Comment: You'd either send them as command-line arguments or you'd store them in some persistence medium from which that application reads (such as a database).

Comment: You're probably better off doing this using `WCF` e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305650/best-way-to-send-and-receive-messages-between-a-windows-service-and-form-applica

Comment: Another option is to send a message to this application or use some sort of service (WCF for example)

Comment: Simplest form of what David suggests is a file in the Windows app's root directory that it just looks for on load, if args are really to be avoided (can't see why tbh). Going further you could do a true remote comms set up using Inter-Process Communication, but that seems overkill for your situation.

Comment: sending through command-line means passing as argv parameters and that don't work. I can't also edit the code of the windows application.
I need to use the existing code and run it through my program.

Comment: @shahar If you can't edit that code, it either already takes the parameters in some form, or you won't be able to at all...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth is there any way to find out how and than send the certain parameters through my code?

Comment: @shahar Other than decompiling the codebase, no. If you are going to those lengths it very likely doesn't know about those two parameters otherwise that information would be made available without the need to decompile.